# Node.JS & Sequelize defining relations

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

There're 2 models, Customer & Order
In model Order define

```
Order.belongsTo(Customer {foreignKey: 'customer_id', as: 'customer'});
```

In model Customer define

```
Customer.hasMany(Order, {foreignKey: 'customer_id', as: 'orders'});
```

Got this error

```
Error: customer.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
```

....

How define these without error?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    var config = require('../config/environment');
    var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

    var db = {
      Sequelize,
      sequelize: new Sequelize(config.mysql.uri, config.mysql.options)
    };

   db.Customer = db.sequelize.import(modal_path);  //your schema
   db.Order = db.sequelize.import(modal_path);  //your schema

   db.Customer.hasMany(db.Order, {
      foreignKey: 'customer_id'
    });

    db.Order.belongsTo(db.Customer, {
      foreignKey: 'customer_id',
      targetKey: 'Id'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you define a model and its associations the same file. I suggest you define associations in separate file from model file. E.g.:

- `order.js`: define `Order` model
- `customer.js`: define `Customer` model
- `association.js`: define association between `Order` and `Customer`